# Unable to getting value from the parameters in ssrs

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I am trying the pass parameters to my ssrs report. In the report i added the parameters and trying to display the report it is working fine when i selected the "None" option in "Available values" tab 
[image]

and "No Default Value" option in the "Default Values" property in ssrs parameters.

[image]

In above condition report is running properly.

But when i am providing the field values from the sharepoint list in "Default values" like below :

[image]

Then it is throwing error during the report preview that "Expected parameter is not supplied" like below:

[image]

What should be the problem ? Please provide anyone has any solution for this.

Thanks in advance. 
Eshwer

Comment: You should tell us what datasets you have, in which order they are, and what their queries are like. In addition, have you checked if the parameter fcTitle has the correct name (in the screenshot we only see the label).

Comment: there is no database i m getting from values from sharepoint list and parameter name all thing i already checked that is not a name problem

Comment: I'm not sure how Sharepoint mode works in SSRS, but don't you still have *datasets* (so not "data *bases*")?

Comment: yes.. i am using the enesys for get sharepoint lists in ssrs in dataset form.

Comment: Is your "Available Values" setting still "None"?

Answer (score 0):

From your above question I can only deduct you have not supplied the `sp_New_HoursByCustomer` dataset the `@fcTitle` parameter.

You should check the parameters options in this dataset and ensure this is set to an `in` and not an `=` comparison.